# Subtraction between two queries

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have 2 database tables:

`table B` is a set of people, `table A` is a set of people from `table B`

```
Table A = (no, id, date) no is PK, id refer to table B

Table B = (id, name) id is PK
```

My goal is to **get data of people (id and name) who didn't attend on a given date** (like today for example) the theory seems simple, set of B substract by set of A who attend (in today) but how can I do this in SQL query? I think about first query substracted by second query but got confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from b where 
not exists (select no from A where A.id=B.id and date=@yourdate)
```

Comment: @yourdate isn't postgresql style (`$1` would be for example)

Comment: wow, what a quick reply. thanks a lot. it's exactly the result what i want

Answer (score 1):

If I understood properly it would be something like this:

```
select b.id, b.name from tableB b where b.id not in (
   select b.id from tableA a
   inner join tableB b on a.id = p.id
   where a.date = CURRENT_DATE)
```

Comment: `convert` is not a PostgreSQL function (not even a standard SQL function)

Comment: There is no need to convert a DATE to a string literal. Just compare the two dates directly. (And `getdate()` is not a PostgreSQL function either)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name replaced with `now()`, but if I don't convert it to char, won't it compare the time as well?

Comment: A PostgreSQL `date` column does not have a time part.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name then to use the `now()` (that has the time part), I've to compare it like this right?

Comment: Use `CURRENT_DATE` instead, that does not have a time part.

Comment: and in any case, this query is returning the people that *did* attend on that date, not what the OP requested